# Evaluate large Groovy script in in GroovyShell

Tags: grails, groovy, groovyshell

I'm using GroovyConsole to evaluate scripts I get from external sources. So the code to evaluate is dynamic and I don't have control over it. Actually is written into a database and I have to read it as a String. Not perfect, but that's how it is.

What I'm doing right now:

```
private GroovyShell shell

def processScript( def script){
    if (script) {
        try{
            shell.evaluate (script, 'some_random_name')
        }catch( e ){
            log.warn "Could not process script: $e"
        }
    }   
}
```

This usually works. But now we got a large script (~3000 LOC) and it throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!` because the script is larger than 64K.

I tried to dump the script into a file and use a BufferedReader, but it throws the same Exception.

So is there a better way to evaluate dynamic Groovy code from within a Groovy method?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your script reach the java limit for a method. I think the only solution is to split your script in many scripts in some way.
[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192896/how-to-circumvent-the-method-too-large-error-in-java-compilation)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question: I have no control over the script, I get it from an external source

Comment: @moeTi I don't think there's anything you can do if you can't change the script, it's a JVM limit on method size, and this script goes into a `run` method of a Groovy `Script` based class

Comment: Well you can split the script in an automated way after you read it from the external source. I don't think it's easy think to do, bat I don't see any other solution because of the java intrinsic limit.

Comment: @tim_yates yeah I actually thought so... well ok then I'll have to find a workaround